# A dropdown menu who have dropdown's inside (Bootstrap-navbar) for tablet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I tried to make a navbar with a dropdown menu inside, but in this, i wan't a dropdown menu inside. But when i click on it, the menu close. I wan't to block this function who when i click on it disapears, because i think it's because of that it cannot works. I saw a thing about stopPropagation on https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/3383 but i don't know where i can declare this, and it isn't a formular.

EDIT : I can't use li class="dropdown-submenu" because when you are on a mobile or a tablet, the menu close when you touch a link in it.

There is my code :

```
<div class="bs-docs-example">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="/app/alink">Title</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Article A<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/app/alink">Title Article 1-A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/app/alink">Title Article 2-A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More ...<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Article B<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="/app/alink">article 1-B</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Article C<b class="caret"></b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Article D<b class="caret"></b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another solution. I added that after my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Dropdown can't works with this solution, so i used "dropdown-submenu" to fix that (Thanks @Schmalzy for that). So when i touch a link, the submenu open. the submenu can't works normally on a tablet without the code above.

Answer (score 0):

## You can use responsive dropdown menu of bootstrap3.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation" style="height: 1px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="./getting-started">Getting started</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./css">CSS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./components">Components</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./javascript">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./customize">Customize</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Bootstrap V2.3.2 as you can see in this link 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

You can upgrade your bootstrap into Version 3 or use this style to fix the problem

```
/*Fix navbar dropdown collapsed on mobile devices*/
.dropdown-backdrop {
    position: static;
}
```

Thanks to http://yogarelax.harpoonmysite.com/